# Why does Java casting have such a strange syntax?

Tags: java, casting

In Java, when you cast, let’s say, a double to an int, you do this.

```
int x = (int)(2.5 * 0.4);
```

In Python, we have this much nicer to read syntax.

```
x = int(2.5 * 0.4)
```

Where does this strange form of casting come from? Why is it used?

**EDIT:**
How is this primarily opinion based? I am looking for **factual** history on why and where this syntax came from. Please reconsider.

Comment: *Where does this strange form of casting come from?* Blame [tag:C] for [that](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)

Comment: This isn't a real question

Comment: `int(...)` looks like a method call

Comment: *"How is this primarily opinion based?"* - From your use of the loaded word "strange" ... I think.

Comment: @StephenC But, that is only the OP(me)’s opinion, the answerer doesn’t have an opinion in it.

Comment: Questions like this implicitly invite the Answers to express an opinion; i.e. argue with you.  That is bad in a SO question.  The correct way for you (as a question asker) to deal with this is to censor yourself; i.e. refrain from starting the argument!

Comment: *"The answerer doesn’t have an opinion in it."* -  If you are referring to me, you are very wrong.  I have a strong opinion on it.  But I resisted your invitation to express it.  The problem is that a lot of (newbie) SO users won't resist ... so we try to close questions like this to PREVENT pointless debates / flamewars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java's syntax was deliberately and consciously modelled on C (and to a lesser degree) C++ syntax.

Both C and C++ use `(<type>) <expr>` as the syntax for type casting.

So ...

> Where does this strange form of casting come from?

C and C++

> Why is it used?

To further the *Java design goal* of syntactically similarity with C and C++.

---

This may seem strange to you.  However, in the context in which Java was originally designed, the C & C++ languages were dominant.  The designers needed to make it easy for C & C++ programmers to transition to Java.  If they had ignored this, Java would most likely never have taken off.

Comment: Beautifully and concisely answered!

Answer (score 1):

Both of those styles have been around for a while: functional and C-like. Given C's prevalence as a code, Java mimicked the style. C++ actually allowed both styles. Python had different goals in choosing its style conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Java was invented at a time when there were a huge number of C programmers in the professional work force, and a slightly smaller number of C++ programmers.  The language designers deliberately made the syntax of Java very similar to C and C++, so that this large horde of people would find it easier to learn, and adapt to Java more easily.  C-style casting is just one of many syntactic elements in C that Java also uses.